# How to store List<List<Integer>> in spring data rest?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-rest

I wanted a model that would serialize to object like that

```
{
  frames = [
    [0,1,2,3],
    [4,5,4,3],
    [2,1,0]
  ]
}
```

Right now I don't know how to do that, so I did that instead

```
 * Created by michael on 26/08/15.
 */
@Entity
public class Frame {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    public Frame(List<Integer> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Frame() {}

    public List<Integer> getData() {

        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Integer> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    @ElementCollection
    @NotNull
    List<Integer> data;
}

@Entity
public class DacChannel {
    @Id
    private int number;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

    @NotNull
    private List<Frame> frames;

    public DacChannel(int number, List<Frame> frames) {
        setNumber(number);
        setFrames(frames);
    }

    public DacChannel() {
    }

    public int getNumber() {

        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public List<Frame> getFrames() {
        return frames;
    }

    public void setFrames(List<Frame> frames) {
        this.frames = frames;
    }

}
```

But it's not working properly also. I'm able to create to create this entity with post request

```
{
    "number": 0,
    "frames": [
        {"data": [1,2,3]},
        {"data": [3,4,5]}
    ]
}
```

But somehow this

```
{
    "number": 1,
    "frames": [
        {"data": [1,2,3]},
        {"data": [3,4,5]}
    ]
}
```

gives me an error.

```
nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [demo.model.board.DacChannel] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=frames, rootBeanClass=class demo.model.board.DacChannel, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]] with root cause

javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [demo.model.board.DacChannel] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=frames, rootBeanClass=class demo.model.board.DacChannel, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeInserts(ActionQueue.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaMergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaMergeEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:886)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:868)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:876)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:863)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

So I'm like "What null are you talking about, I've included all properties in request body!". I don't understand what's going on.

Also, Can I somehow do what I wanted to initially with jpa? Maybe using @Lob or something? Or maybe I can do that easily with mongodb? I use postres and h2 (for tests) right now.

EDIT1

After some experiments I've been able to find that after removing NotNull annotation here, everything works fine. Still, my question is stays the same. Can I do what I wanted to do initially (with mongodb or @Lob?). And what is the reason for this error I got? I don't want to remove NonNull annotation.

@ElementCollection
List data;

Comment: JPA has nothing to do with the exception as such (other than your JPA provider handing off handling). It is "Bean validation". The JSON stuff is not input to JPA so of little interest

Comment: @NeilStockton Yeah, ok. Not very helpful, sorry.

Comment: Please share the code block where this exception thrown. Frames couldn't mapped from json to your objec correctly .

Comment: So the message says "DacChannel" has a null that shouldn't be there. Look at that class and there is only one place that can be ... "frames". So why is it null?

Comment: @İlkerKorkut There is no code that throwing this exception. It's a spring-data-rest. It's all automatic.

Comment: @NeilStockton If I would know that, I wouldn't be here.

Comment: @user1685095 How do you populating with your requestbody to your `DacChannel` class' frames property.

Comment: @İlkerKorkut It's done by spring-data-rest.

Comment: @user1685095 Okay but how do you mapping your requestbody with that entity please share controller's your entity save operation code block.

Comment: @İlkerKorkut have you worked with spring-data-rest?

Comment: @user1685095 ok spring-data-`rest` , it seems problem is request payload. I will share answer.

Comment: If you already know that, then why not put DEBUG in your code and print out when this field is set, and then you know why it is null. But then you'd know that ...

Comment: @NeilStockton Because all the rest of a code is generated by spring-data-rest. Where do you think I should put a breakpoint?

Comment: @user1685095 May you try to remove `@ElementCollection` from data property and add `@Embeddable` on Frame class ? There is http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1821 the doc about jpa , i think its not mapping automaticly now.

Comment: @İlkerKorkut That's what I've started from. JPA can't map such entities. And if you would make Frame class Embeddable then you would need to use ElementCollection in class that reference it.

Comment: Put your breakpoint in the entity that should have its value set ... the constructor for a start, then the setter of that field, and if not set then go backwards and find what should be calling it and why it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's bean validation that is not working, not the way you store the data.

Object you are trying to save does not have properly set list of frames.
probably there is no `dacChannel.setFrames(…)` called.

Fix this and it should be fine.

Comment: What? What do you mean "object you are trying to save does not have properly set list of frames?". "Probably there is no dacChannel.setFrames() called" Called by whom? It's a spring-data-rest project, it should do this automatically. And if you haven't noticed it works just fine when "number" field is zero.